# Open Graph Object Debugger gives error when have both header and object tags?

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-opengraph

The website I am working from is:

www.randompostsonsocial.com/quote-status.php

I made sure to have tags on both the header as well as the object (maybe that's the problem).

I get the following error on FB (open graph object) debugger..

> Object Missing a Required Value | Object at URL
>   'http://www.randompostsonsocial.com/' of type 'website' is invalid
>   because a required property 'og:title' of type 'string' was not
>   provided.

I don't know what steps I may have not taken, this is my first try.

I have included the object with the parameters as well as in the header maybe that's redundant don't know what way there is around that.

Any input on my code might help. not sure.

Comment: No you don't have any tags. This is what you send back to Facebook https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/echo/?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.randompostsonsocial.com%2Fquote-status.php

Comment: Alright that resolved the issue for me, one tag needed to be removed, thank you